# How to create deploy process to ZIP ./dist folder with Angular-Cli

Tags: node.js, zip, angular-cli

I need to create a deploy package. That would after `ng build --prod` will create `SOME_APP.zip` file any name I will put in deploy.config.json or anywhere.

There is a way to do it without using webpack-plugins?

Comment: I guess ng build --prod is supposed to zip it but it somehow doesn't work for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this kinda works but probably it's not how package.json was supposed to be used:

```
  "scripts": {
    "all": "ng test; ng build --prod; zip -r dist/app.zip dist/app;"
  },
```

in other proj I see ppl relying on Jenkins and/or deploy tools to zip it.

Comment: That's what I did

Answer (score 0):

Windows + 7-Zip Version:

- Zip in dist-Folder without the folders dist/app-name
- File is named according to your app-name and version, leading to a local history of version-builds if something's going wrong..
- assuming that `outputPath` in `angular.json` is not changed..

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod && cd dist && c:\\\"Program Files\"\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a %npm_package_name%_%npm_package_version%.zip ./%npm_package_name%/*",
```